# How to put a deep link on the homepage in ios?

Tags: swift

For example, I have a link to [www.exemple.com](http://www.exemple.com) and I want the user to click that link to be taken to the home screen of my app.

Is there a regex to take the home screen of the app?

Comment: check apple's documentation on that
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app

Comment: I checked the documentation but it didn't solve my problem. I'm using Universal Links and I made some settings in the apple-app-site-association.

I believe that I need to put some path in the apple-app-site-association that makes reference to the site (www.exemple.com) that I want to redirect to the app